# create soap message from Data Contract

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, datacontractserializer

I have a WCF service and I consume it using c#. Basically I add the service reference and consume service operations through it.

This service is being exposed using basicHttpBinding. I would like to allow soapBinding too and give some samples of the soap to my clients.

Is it possible to get soap xml from DataContract class? I mean, I would like to somehow, get xml using my existing code.

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}



[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Import(IEnumerable<Foo> foos);
}
```

c# client:

```
var client = new ws.ServiceClient();

var foo = new Foo{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test"
};


client.Import(new[] { foo });
```

Just in case I was not clear enough, I would like to get soap xml reusing code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a plain request for documentation or something you can use WCF tracing.

Simple and generic soulution for all yours services.

At your system.serviceModel

```
<system.serviceModel>
...
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>     
....
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and add system.diagnostics element

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4"/>
  </switches>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Then after a service call check service log at (c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog) there will be a plain request.

Or if you want to get it in your client code. 
Use WCF message inspector. Sample use http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article121